# sjPlot's tab_model() and summary() function give different results in multilevel model

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I'm a little puzzled because this has never happened to me before when using the tab_model function - I'm writing up the results for a paper, and  when I use tab_model() from the sjPlot package (to obtain an html, nicer looking table) I've found that some of the results, especifically the p-values, change drastically between the two functions.
The model was:

`m.1 = lmer(EMG ~  Time_sd* Cond.num + EDA_cs + Arousal+ (1+Time_sd* Cond.num|SUBJECT) + (1+Time_sd |Video), data=nonadata, REML=TRUE, control = lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))`

Output:

```
Formula: EMG_10000 ~ Time_sd * Cond.num + EDA_cs + Arousal + (1 + Time_sd *  
    Cond.num | SUBJECT) + (1 + Time_sd | Video)
   Data: nonadata
Control: lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))

REML criterion at convergence: 168357.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-15.7964  -0.2780  -0.0459   0.2062  22.0285 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name             Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 SUBJECT  (Intercept)       6.0407  2.4578                    
          Time_sd           1.5212  1.2334    0.58            
          Cond.num         20.9494  4.5771   -0.57 -0.51      
          Time_sd:Cond.num  3.3021  1.8172   -0.38 -0.39  0.49
 Video    (Intercept)       1.6525  1.2855                    
          Time_sd           0.1237  0.3516   0.83             
 Residual                  75.6901  8.7000                    
Number of obs: 23425, groups:  SUBJECT, 48; Video, 8

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      -6.307e-01  6.268e-01  1.952e+01  -1.006  0.32663    
Time_sd          -6.996e-01  2.252e-01  2.524e+01  -3.106  0.00464 ** 
Cond.num          1.279e+00  1.131e+00  1.310e+01   1.130  0.27861    
EDA_cs            2.776e-01  6.152e-02  1.357e+04   4.513 6.45e-06 ***
Arousal           3.042e-02  5.338e-02  8.022e+03   0.570  0.56879    
Time_sd:Cond.num  8.496e-01  3.805e-01  1.515e+01   2.233  0.04104 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

but `tab_model(m.1)`:

[image]

For example, the Time_sd x Cond.num interaction went from p =.04 to p=.026.
Any idea of what is possibly going on? The parameter estimates don't seem to change, only the p-values.

Comment: What package do you use to fit the mixed model? Possibly `nlme` together with `lmerTest`? I suspect the difference comes from the different methods to calculate the degrees of freedom. `tab_model` uses the Wald method by default whereas `lmerTest` uses Satterthwaite. What do you get if you use `tab_model(m1, df.method = "satterthwaite", show.df = TRUE)`?

Comment: I use lme4; I tried your suggestion and I get the following error message. But yes, I think you're right, the issue has to do with how tab_model() calculates the dfs.
```tab_model(m.1, df.method = "satterthwaite", show.df = TRUE) 
Error in if (fam.info$is_linear) transform <- NULL else transform <- "exp" : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
Could not access model information.```

Comment: And when I try p.val="kr", for Kenward Rogers, I get the following error:
```Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'forceSymmetric': cannot allocate vector of size 4.1 Gb```

I suspect my dataset is too big for tab_model()? I have 23405 dfs...

Comment: Please add the function calls you're using to your question. Yes, the Kenward-Roger method is computationally intensive.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by adding the function call? do you mean the code? The first error is for this line:
```tab_model(m.1, df.method = "satterthwaite", show.df = TRUE)```
The second error in the second comment is for this line:
```tab_model(m.1, p.val="kr")```

Comment: I meant the function call of the model itself (`lmer` I presume). And please add this to your question, not the comments.

Comment: Thank you. It's difficult to diagnose the error that `tab_model` with Satterthwaite dfs gives you. But I'm pretty sure that the different degrees of freedom are the source of the discrepancies. As a final confirmation, you could run `tab_model` with just the option `show.df = TRUE` without changing the `df.method`. I strongly suspect that the degrees of freedom differ from those given by `lmerTest`.

Comment: Please can you edit your post to include the full output of `summary(m.1)`. I agree that is likely to do with the choice of degrees of freedom, which underlines the problems with computing p-values for mixed model estimates in the first place.

Comment: Well, my field (media psychology) does not really let you publish without a p-value, so that's not really an option...
I edited and added the full output of the summary. Thank you both for the input. I'm just going to manually edit the tab_model to match the summary; after reading quite a bit, I think the difference is that tab_model uses Wald approximation but lmer uses Satterthwaite, which I understand is more conservative and more appropriate.

Comment: *"my field (media psychology) does not really let you publish without a p-value"* ! Then I'm sorry to tell you that you're in the wrong field. I would recommend that you explain why you chose Satterthwaite's approximation, rather than say, Kenward-Rogers or any other arbitrary choice. Note that `lme4::lmer` does not produce p-values for mixed models, and that's for very good reasons. I assume you are using something like `lmertest` instead.

Comment: "then I'm sorry to tell you that you're in the wrong field". Ha. That's quite the statement. I'll try to not take offense for that.

Comment: I don't mean to cause offence. But there are right and wrong ways to do things and if you work in a field that *"does not really let you publish without a p-value"* then something is wrong, something is terribly wrong, and I don't know what else to say.